# correct way to return a value in a function, and then check the function's value

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out the right way to return a value inside a function.
Later in my code I need to check this function's value (true or false) and execute an action depending if it is true or false.

Here is the function I'm trying to set up (you'll notice there is a function inside my main function, I don't know if php allows that ?) :

```
public function checkPrivileges($getprivileges) {

        $directory = $_SESSION['cwd'];                  // current directory
        $user = $_SESSION['simple_auth']['username'];   // get username
        $repository = gatorconf::get('repository');     // get base repertory of the file manager
        $userdir = $repository.DS.'user'.DS.$user;      // user's repertory

        function scanDirectory($userdir = '', $directory){
            $folders = glob($userdir . '/*' , GLOB_ONLYDIR);
            foreach($folders as $folder){
                if (($folder == $directory && gator::checkPermissions('rp')) || (gator::checkPermissions('rw')) || ($userdir == $directory && gator::checkPermissions('rp'))) {
                    return true;
                }

                $scan_result = scanDirectory($folder, $directory);

                if($scan_result) {
                   return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        scanDirectory($userdir, $directory);

        if ((gator::checkPermissions('rw')) || ($userdir == $directory && gator::checkPermissions('rp'))) {
                $getprivileges = true;
        }

        $getprivileges = scanDirectory($userdir, $directory);   // user's privileges
        return $getprivileges;

    }
```

The `scanDirectory function` is working fine, but I am not sure if `$getprivileges` is returned to the `checkPrivileges function` (it's supposed to be either true or false), is this the right way to do it ?

Later on my code the main page is displayed through an include, and inside this page I have to check if `checkPrivileges` is true or false, and display something accordingly to it.

Here is how I currently check `checkPrivileges` on the page :

```
<?php
    if (gator::checkPrivileges($getprivileges) == true){
        echo "it's a bingo";
    }else {
        echo "that was close";
    }
?>
```

Needless to say this is not working. The script stops executing.

I'm looking for some help to get my function to work, and if possible some explanations about what I didn't understand, I'll have to this kind of stuff quite often in the future.

Thanks for the help !

**(16/12/2015 15h50) Update :**

After your suggestions this is what I have right now :

```
public function checkPrivileges($getprivileges) {
        $directory = $_SESSION['cwd'];                  // current directory
        $user = $_SESSION['simple_auth']['username'];   // get username
        $repository = gatorconf::get('repository');     // get base repertory of the file manager
        $userdir = $repository.DS.'user'.DS.$user;      // user's repertory


        if ((gator::checkPermissions('rw')) || ($userdir == $directory && gator::checkPermissions('rp'))) {
                return true;
        }

        $getprivileges = $this->scanDirectory($userdir, $directory);   // user's privileges
        return $getprivileges;

    }

    private function scanDirectory($userdir = '', $directory) {
        $folders = glob($userdir . '/*' , GLOB_ONLYDIR);
        foreach($folders as $folder){
            if (($folder == $directory && gator::checkPermissions('rp')) || (gator::checkPermissions('rw')) || ($userdir == $directory && gator::checkPermissions('rp'))) {
                return true;
            }

            if($this->scanDirectory($folder, $directory) === true) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;

        scanDirectory($userdir, $directory);
    }
```

So if I fully understand what I did, the `checkPrivileges method` will return true if if `((gator::checkPermissions('rw')) || ($userdir == $directory && gator::checkPermissions('rp')))` and if not (and this is where I have a problem), it is supposed call the scanDirectory function.

It looks like no value gets returned from the scanDirectory function, my page will just stop executing at this line of code :

```
<?php
    if (gator::checkPrivileges($getprivileges) == true) {
        echo "yata";
    }else {
    echo "nope";
    }
?>
```

To be more specific it looks like there is something wrong either with the modifications I made to the scanDirectory function, or with this part of checkPrivileges :

```
$getprivileges = $this->scanDirectory($userdir, $directory);   // user's privileges
        return $getprivileges;
```

Thanks again for all the help

Comment: what is the error message? does it give you any?

Comment: no error message unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't make a function inside a class method (your socalled main function). You should make it a private function inside your class, you can than call it using $this->FUNCTIONNAME(); as shown:

```
Class Privileges {

  public function checkPrivileges($getprivileges) {
    $directory = $_SESSION['cwd'];                  // current directory
    $user = $_SESSION['simple_auth']['username'];   // get username
    $repository = gatorconf::get('repository');     // get base repertory of the file manager
    $userdir = $repository.DS.'user'.DS.$user;      // user's repertory

    // I think you should delete this, because you call it without assing the return data to a variable.
    //$this->scanDirectory($userdir, $directory);

    if ((gator::checkPermissions('rw')) || ($userdir == $directory && gator::checkPermissions('rp'))) {
            //$getprivileges = true;
            return true;
    }
    // Why are you setting $getprivileges to true above this comment and 
    // than re-setting it below this comment? If the below line is no longer
    // necessary if the earlier conditions where met you should simply 
    // return true above this comment (as I have done for you now)
    $getprivileges = $this->scanDirectory($userdir, $directory);   // user's privileges
    return $getprivileges;

  }

  private function scanDirectory($userdir = '', $directory) {
        $folders = glob($userdir . '/*' , GLOB_ONLYDIR);
        foreach($folders as $folder){
            if (($folder == $directory && gator::checkPermissions('rp')) || (gator::checkPermissions('rw')) || ($userdir == $directory && gator::checkPermissions('rp'))) {
                return true;
            }

            if($this->scanDirectory($folder, $directory) === true) {
               return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
  }
}
```

I have commented some things I think you should consider next time

Comment: `$scan_result = $this->scanDirectory($folder, $directory);` also on the scanDirectory function

Comment: Thanks for the answer and all theses details, about the code you suggest me to delete, yes I've done some changes to the function and forgot to modify this code ($getprivileges used to be defined before it). However I should have mentionned that my function (or method) is already inside a class (named 'gator') so no problem about that. I'll try your suggestions and come back to update, thank you for the help. Also, was my way to check the function correct ? (my second block of code)

Comment: @Ceeee I'm not to sure to get what you meant :s

Comment: @apatik scanDirectory is recursive. in the middle of that function is calling itself. so you need to use $this->scanDirectory.

Comment: @apatik The function seems to be fine (it is recursive indeed), so as long as the checkPermissions() funtion works correctly it should work. You could omit the $scan_result variable and combine those lines (I edited the answer for that) to make it more efficient.

Comment: Thanks ! I was just about to update my post with what I have right now. It looks way better already but there is still something not working, probably something I didn't fully understood, my post will be updated in about 5 minutes